# Can I run a ruby source code using raw.github.com

Tags: ruby

For example i want to make a program that will copy the source from a specific file located on my repo to a local file on my computer and eventually run it. Is it possible to do something like that and if yes, how?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Not really, i have no idea how to do this. Im trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a request and save to a file like this:

```
require 'net/http'

file_content = Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dx7/9215951/raw"))
File.write("/tmp/mycode.rb", file_content)
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, i guess i wasn't specific. I want to write a program that will copy the content from github to a file on my PC.

Comment: @b1o You mean like... git? In any case, there are any number of ways this could be done, including just accessing it and using openuri to snarf the content, or using the git api, or...

Answer (score 0):

Using [Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) I wrote a similar application.

The basic gist of cloning a repo would look something like this. Its not clearly documented but I dug deep enough to figure it out.

```
creds = Rugged::Credentials::SshKey.new(username:  'git', 
                                        publickey: ENV['SSH_PUBLIC_KEY'],
                                        privatekey: ENV['SSH_PRIVATE_KEY'],
                                        passphrase: ENV['SSH_PASSPHRASE'])
Rugged::Repository.clone_at(git_url, 'absolute_path_to_directory_to_store', credentials: creds)
```

Not sure if this answers your question as it's not clear exactly what you're looking to do. Note that that snippet will clone an entire repo not just the contents of a repo into a file...`I want to write a program that will copy the content from github to a file on my PC`